# Конвертация mathtype в mathml

Tags: c#

Добрый день, требуется реализовать программу на c#, которая бы конвертировала содержимое docx-документа в xhtml-файл. Все бы ничего, но в документе формулы набраны с помощью mathtype. Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли их каким-то образом перегнать в mathml? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Я знаю, что mathtype-плагин для word позволяет все это сделать, но это долгая история, почему нужен свой инструмент :)

Comment: а разве mathtype не хранит формулы в формате mathml в docx-файле?

Comment: нет, они в бинарном виде хранятся, в этом и проблема

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте [MathType Software Development Kit](http://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/) (бесплатен). SDK включает примеры конвертации. Потребуется:

1. поместить объект MathType OLE в буфер обмена
2. вызвать функцию конвертации
3. извлечь результат из буфера обмена.

Вкратце

- MTInitAPI, MTTermAPI - начать, завершить
- MTSetMTPrefs, MTGetPrefsFromFile - выбрать предпочтения
- MTXFormSetTranslator - убедиться что OLE встроен в MathML
- MTXFormEqn - преобразовать

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду разбираться.